# SharePoint. How to run timerjob every 90 minutes

Tags: timer-jobs

I have a web.config setting like IntervalInMinutes. I would like to use the setting value to create my SPSchedule instance and run my job. The interval should be set in minutes.

I know how to use SPMinuteSchedule and run the job every 0 < n < 60 minute or how to use SPHourSchedule and run the job every 0 < n < 24 hours, But what if I want to have 90 or 2000 minutes interval as the setting value?

So, the question is: what should I do to run the job with the minutes interval 0 < n < 100000?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8902c519-7cd0-494a-91ce-4371333bd89a), it appears you are somewhat limited in how you can use the `SPMinuteSchedule` for an interval greater than 60 minutes.

As one user in that thread suggests, your best option may be to set the `SPMinuteSchedule.Interval` to 45, then only have the timer job "do its work" every *other* time it runs. Not the cleanest solution, I know, but that would do the trick.